# Reading and Writing TXT Files in Java

Tags: java, filereader, readline

I know this is probably entry level stuff but I need some help.
Im working on this for a class
I've exhausted my class resources so I'm in need of some help

Also I am using Eclipse and it's not showing any errors

I have an array that has been written to a txt file. I am having trouble reading it.
Basically the program forces the customer to order three times, the writer writes it three times, exactly like it should, but I'm not sure how to get the reader to read it three times, it's only reading the first.

```
 public static void writeOrderHeader(String name, String returning) throws Exception
        {
            File file;
            file = new File("order.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            pw.println(name);
            pw.println(returning);
            pw.close();
        }

        public static void writeOrderFile(String product, String size, String type, int qty, double total) throws Exception
        {
            String file = "order.txt";
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            pw.println(product);
            pw.println(type);
            pw.println(size);
            pw.println(qty);
            pw.println(total);
            pw.close();
        }
        public static void confirmation() throws IOException
        {
            File file;
            BufferedReader bf = null;
            String name, returning, product, type, size, qty, total;
            int intQty;
            double dblTotal;
            file = new File("order.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
            name = bf.readLine();
            returning = bf.readLine();
            product = bf.readLine();
            size = bf.readLine();
            type = bf.readLine();
            qty = bf.readLine();
            total = bf.readLine();
            fr.close();
            intQty = Integer.parseInt(qty);
            dblTotal = Double.parseDouble(total);
            String nameOutputMsg = "Welcome " + name + ".\n";
            String returnOutputMsg = "Your returning customer status is " + returning + ".\n";
            String productOutputMsg = "Your first choice to buy a/n size " + type + " " + size + " " + product + " with the quantity of " + intQty + ".\n";
            String totalOutputMsg = "Your first Order total is $" + String.format("%.2f", dblTotal) + ".\n";
            String goodbyeOutputMsg = "Thanks for ordering at ThinkGeek!";
            String outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + productOutputMsg + totalOutputMsg + goodbyeOutputMsg;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputMsg); 
        }
```

Comment: There is far too much code here for us to help you. As you have using Eclipse you are access to **excellent** debugging. Add logging (or output to console if you have to) and determine where things are going wrong. Then step through the code with a debugger. Once you have identified the exact problem, you will probably already know how to solve it - if you do not, create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post a new question here.

Comment: Another note for your future coding and posting here: **stick to Java naming conventions** - classes are **always** in `PascalCase`. These conventions are compiled with be the entire Java community, and by not doing so you make your code very hard to read. Further, whilst your formatting it okayish, your use of whitespace is horrible - it makes the code even harder to take in. Remove unnecessary whitespace and let Eclipse autoformat do the rest.

Comment: I've just read some of the above code, but wouldn't it be easier to store orders in a central array or list first and then write it to the file? Doing so would avoid the reading operation when adding new orders in the current session.

Comment: I've debugged and ran the code and ect in Eclipse, there are no errors coming up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// reading

```
    File f = new File(Address);
    FileReader r = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(r);
    String out = "";
    String k="";
    while( (out=b.readLine()) != null) {
        k+=out;
    }
    b.close();
```

//so the String k is the answer

//writing :

```
    File file = new File(Address);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(YourString);  
    bw.close();
```

Comment: Im sorry I am like a super noob and this class explains next to nothing, what is String K doing?

Comment: the value of String k is "" at first
then i read from the file character by character and add it to String k